# LPTHW 48: nosetest says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute ' ' while output seems correct?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on LPTHW and I'm trying to understand my error.

This is my code:

```
class lexicon:

def __init__(self, words):
    self.words = words

def scan(self):
    direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
    verb = ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']
    stop = ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']
    noun = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']
    number = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

    thewords = self.words.split()
    output = []

    for i in thewords:
        if i in direction:
            output.append(('direction', i ))
            print(output)

lexicon('north').scan()
```

I've put in the print statement to check if the output is correct. The actual output:

```
[('direction', 'north')]
```

I'm trying to get my nose test script running with this:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon

def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
```

But when I execute it:

```
thewords = self.words.split()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words'
```

The output of the script seems to match what the nose script expects, a tupil with those values. But the error seems to say that I gave it a string and it wants something else? I've searched on the error message but I can't wrap my head around what it's trying to tell me here.

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Look at `lexicon('north').scan()` and `lexicon.scan("north")`. Don't they look different?

Comment: *I'm working on LPTHW*. That might already be the problem. I recommend *strongly* you step away from that book, and move to [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) instead. The latter because it is **much better**, and up to date for Python 3. See https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints as well.

Comment: Your interaction with the class isn't right at all. You're calling an instance method in the class with an instance of the wrong class. What's odd is that you do it correctly in the script itself; why'd you not write the test the same?